# How to write exif tags when creating MP4 file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I see lots of questions asking about how to add EXIF tags to MP4 another other media files with ffmpeg.  I am not interested in doing this.  I currently have an exiftool command that I am running after the fact, but this takes some time because it has to rewrite the entire file.

What I would like to do instead is to add the tags to the MP4 file *while I am originally creating it* so that I only have to write the file once.

I found [this page](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata) on creating metadata, but it does not list *any* of the metadata I want to set.  In am trying to set all the timestamp tags, making sure they are properly set to UTC when applicable as is the case with some of the track/media timestamps.

Update: I see this question has attracted a downvote and a vote to close due to claims about it being off-topic as it allegedly is not about programming.  I am using ffmpeg in a bash script which does some automation, so I'm not sure why this claim is being made.  There are certainly other similar questions (just look at a few with the ffmpeg tag).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by, *"trying to set all the timestamp tags, making sure they are properly set to UTC when applicable as is the case with some of the track/media timestamps"*.

Comment: @llogan Tags like DateTimeOriginal are stored in the local timezone, while others like TrackCreateDate are store in UTC.  In exiftool, there is an option "QuickTimeUTC" to ensure that the timezone is stored in the appropriate zone for each tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -metadata creation_time="2015-10-21 07:28:00" -map 0 -c copy out.mp4
```

Use `-metadata creation_time="$(date +'%F %T')"` to record the time when your command is launched.

Comment: That looks good, but I didn't see "creation_time" mentioned as a valid tag in the linked documentation page.  I've got five other timestamps I'm trying to set, I'll try putting an underscore between portions of the tag name as I know it (via exiftool) and see if ffmpeg recognizes them all.

Comment: I got this from the ffmpeg mailing list at https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2016-March/031142.html
Can you confirm that it changes the following keys (in exiftool): `Create Date`, `Modify Date`, `File Modification Date/Time`, `File Access Date/Time`, `File Inode Change Date/Time`, `Track Create Date`, `Track Modify Date`, `Media Create Date`, `Media Modify Date`

Comment: `creation_time` can be local or UTC. According to the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Date): "Time is local time unless Z is appended, in which case it is interpreted as UTC. If the year-month-day part is not specified it takes the current year-month-day."

Comment: I tried it and "creation_time" sets (in exiftool -s format) `CreateDate`, `ModifyDate`, `TrackCreateDate`, `TrackModifyDate`, `MediaCreateDate`, and `MediaModifyDate`.  However, I tried a few things but have not been able to figure out how to set `DateTimeOriginal`.

Comment: Also, even though I specified the time once in local time, all the time fields were set to UTC, even though ModifyDate and CreateDate should be set to local time.